# changing SYS V shared memory owner to root

Tags: linux-kernel

i have created a shared memory segment using normal user and changed its UID and GID to zero, after changing this owner of shared memory segment become root. The question is that why this segment is removed by user which is not having privileged level.

Here is the program which changing the owner of shared memory to root.

```
{

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        int ret = 0;
        int shmid = 0;
        int key = 0xbade;
        struct shmid_ds shmi = {0};

        shmid = shmget(key, 0x200000, IPC_CREAT|0666);
        if (shmid < 0)
                perror("shmget");

        ret = shmctl(shmid, IPC_STAT, (struct shmid_ds *)&shmi);
        if (ret < 0)
                perror("shmctl");

        shmi.shm_perm.uid = 0;
        shmi.shm_perm.cuid = 0;
        shmi.shm_perm.cgid = 0;
        shmi.shm_perm.gid = 0;

        ret = shmctl(shmid, IPC_SET, (struct shmid_ds *)&shmi);
        if (ret < 0)
                perror("shmctl");

        return 0;
}
}
```

but if i created shared memory segment using root user and changed its UID and GID to normal user XYZ then this segment can be removed without having root owner.

Comment: What do you mean by "segment is removed by user"? The segment is destroyed when the user process ends? Or are you trying to destroy the segment with `shmctl(IPC_RMID)`?

Comment: i mean using rpm command "ipcrm", tried to remove shared memory segment, i am not explicitly removing segment using shmctl(IPC_RMID)

Comment: Actually i have written ipcrm command for our own linux based operating system. So i am testing 'ipcrm' command. my concern is that if we change owner of shared memory segment to root then it should be removed only by user whose having root permissions not by normal user.

Comment: [man ipcrm](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ipcrm.1.html) explicitely says, that object's **creator** is allowed to delete the object: "In order to delete such objects, you must be superuser, or the creator or owner of the object.".

Comment: i agree with you,

Comment: I see no **creator** field in this output.

Comment: There is field called 'owner' in the output of 'ipcs' command which is same as creator. So am changing that only.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you very much for your quick respose. query is resolved. My understanding was wrong, Actually in linux we can,t change the creator of shared memory segment. only owner can be chagned. That's why even after chaning the owner to the root user , normal user can delete the shared memory segment because it is created by normal user only..